# Sumar propiedades de dos objetos en dos arrays diferentes en Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo estos datos (imagen) y quiero sumar el total de "inverter_count" en ambos arrays.

Este es mi codigo y por alguna razón me devuelve "0":

TotalInverters: function() {
      let TotInv = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.design.field_component_metadata.wiring_zones.length; i++) {
        TotInv += this.design.field_component_metadata.wiring_zones[i].inverter[0].inverter_count;
      }
      return TotInv;
    },[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el objeto de consola , en la parte donde declaras la siguiente linea de codigo : `this.design.field_component_metadata.wiring_zones[i].inverter[0].inverter_count;`,
en la seccion del recorrido `wiring_zones[i]` , no puedes poner un indice como si se tratara de un arreglo , debes acceder a los objetos por su nombre , si tuvieras un arreglo podrias hacerlo de esa forma , fijate en el recorrido hasta `wiring_zones` , que este es un objeto no es un arreglo y estas intentado accederlo como un arreglo colocandole un indice `[i]`

Modifique el codigo del recorrido para que de esta forma puedas acceder a las claves hijas de `wiring_zones` utilizando un `for...in` bucle , el codigo a continuación :

```
 TotalInverters: function() { 
  let wiringZones = this.design.field_component_metadata.wiring_zones;
  let TotInv = 0; 
  for(let wiringZone in wiringZones){
      TotInv += wiringZones[wiringZone].inverter[0].inverter_count; 
  } 
  return TotInv;
 }
```

Lo hice a forma de prueba ya que no cuento con tu objeto completo mostrado en consola, cualquier cosa deja tus dudas en los comentarios para ayudarte, suerte :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar 'for each' usando las combinaciones de 'for..in' y 'for..of' ya que debes recorrer tanto objectos como arrays.

- **`for..in`** devuelve el valor `clave` de un objecto para acceder a el con `padre[clave]`.
- **`for..of`** devuelve los objeto de un array, es una sentencia simplificada de `for(let i; i < arr.length; i++){ let objeto = arr[i]}`

```js
//desing.field,wirin.inverter.inverter_count
var desing = {
  filed: {
    wiring : {
      '2222' : {
         inverter: [
            { inv_count: 1},
            { inv_count: 2},
            { inv_count: 3}
         ]
      }
    }
  }
}
function total(){
  let total = 0
  for(let num in desing.filed.wiring){
   for( let inverter of desing.filed.wiring[num].inverter ){
     total +=inverter.inv_count;
   }
  }
  elTotal.value = total
}
```

```html
Total: <input id="elTotal">
<button onclick="total()">calcular</button>
```